# See all posts from everyone in Facebook

Tags: facebook

Facebook now has a per-friend "How many updates?" settings that controls the number of updates that appear in the news feed from that friend. I want to see all updates from all of my friends. Is there any way to change this setting globally or do I have to go through each and every one of my friends to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it in bulk.

"How many updates?" are preset based on your categories for friends and lists.

- Close Friends - All Updates
- Acquaintances - Only Important
- Friends - Most Updates
- Restricted - Most Updates
- Subscribed - Most Updates